# Intent not working in FirebaseFirestore android Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-intent, intentservice

I have code block in which intent should work on some specific condition it was working fine two days ago but now it stops working. Everything is working except intent.

Here is the code.

```
    mFireStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    mFireStore.collection("USERS")
        .whereEqualTo("Number", "+92"+number.text.toString())
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            for (document in documents) {

                if(document.exists()){

                    number.error = "This number already exist"

                }else{

                    val OTP = Intent(this,OTPActivity::class.java)
                    OTP.putExtra("Name",NAME.text.toString())
                    OTP.putExtra("Age","20")
                    OTP.putExtra("District","s")
                    OTP.putExtra("Number",number.text.toString())
                    startActivity(OTP)

                }
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Toast.makeText(this,exception.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

When i take intent out of this firestore block it's working. Don't know what going wrong. Even it was working perfectly fine two days ago

Comment: It's not clear at all to me what you mean by "Everything is working except intent".  Please edit the question to be more clear about what isn't working, and how that is different from what you expect.

Comment: I hve one button , on Button clickk I am checking if the number i am entering is already exist or not in Firestore, If it exist it wil say "This number already exist" else it will start intent and proceed to next activity

Comment: If you mention that this code was working fine 2 days ago, I can assume there no were any changes to it or there was a change (even in your firestore db)?

Comment: I have not changed anything, Even the same code in other project is working and also if i take this intent block out of firebaseFirestore it's working.

Comment: if condition is also working but else condition in which Intent is define not working

Comment: Could you please add any message or error message that could be showing?

Comment: I have added FailureListener it should display a Toast in case of any error but it's not showing any error

Comment: Did you add `OTPActivity ` to the `manifest` ?

Comment: yes i have added @Neeraj

Comment: `this` in `Intent(this,OTPActivity::class.java)` . Maybe change it to `this@OuterAtivityClassName` ?

Comment: I have tried this @Neeraj

Comment: It can't be `this` anyway..

Comment: The problem is only if condition is working, else is not working. If i put this intent in if it's working when i put this in else it's stop working @Neeraj

Comment: Which could only mean that `document.exists()` is always true. Its a logical error then :(. Are you sure the condition you're checking is what you really want ?

Comment: document.exists() can't be true always, It can be null

Comment: Have you changed something in the database?

Comment: Not at all @AlexMamo, If condition is working fine. If i enter any number which is already exists it showing me error. But else case is not working

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan What error do you get?

Comment: If i enter any number which is already exsited in database it showing "This number already exisits" which is if conidition @AlexMamo